# Using wget to get files from local to server to remote server

Tags: wget, local

We have a local server where we carry out much of our web development and then we push this to a live environment so that clients can access.

We often end up with huge tarballs (this one in particular is 6.6Gb) which we need to get from our local server to our remote server.

We use putty as a terminal and WinSCP.

Fetching data over wget is always super quick but is there any way to use wget on the remote server terminal to get the tarball on our local server and if so, what command do we need to use or what else do we need to configure / set up?

We can upload via SFTP / FTP but with huge files, this can take hours or even days!

Comment: If you're going to downvote at least bother adding a comment to explain why.

Comment: Well...the question *is* a bit vague.  Are we to understand you are asking the following: "How do I set up a web server on the local side so that I can use wget on the remote side to pull a file?"  Which looks a little silly, given that you are doing web development.

Answer (score 4):

you better use scp (secure copy)

`scp yourfile user@example.org:/var/www/`

and if you use key authentication you get rid of the password question too (and it's more secure too)

if your tarball (like you wrote in a comment) is named *.tar then your 6GB is not compressed so on your local ubuntu ´bzip2 tarball.tar`and after transfering a`bunzip2 tarball.tar.bz2` will save you a probably lot of time

Comment: But another suggestion (if you just make a few edits you don't have to transfer the whole 6GB use rsync instead

Answer (score 1):

To make thing clear, you want to transfer an archived file from your local server to a web remote server, not local ?

If it's so, using ftp or wget (which is direct download-like) will use the same connection.

But if you really want to use wget, I would move the file in the apache (or equivalent if installed) directory from local server and then use wget with the correct link on the remote server via SSH terminal. This mean that your file will be freely accessible and not secured.

EDIT1 : I suggest you use FTP for senstive file

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Ah okay yeh, makes sense, would just be as slow then as uses same connection as FTP. I don't understand what you mean with your last sentence "I would move the file in the apache (or equivalent if installed) directory from local server and then use wget with the correct link on the remote server via SSH terminal" though. The tarball is currently at a local path like:- z:\server\sites\local\tarball.tar

Comment: I'll go with a concrete example. I use a centOS server with Httpd (Apache), configured to be accessible through web. If I want to share file I copy my file in my dedicated apache location : /var/www/html/files/. Then from anywhere I can use wget www.mysite.com/files/xxx.tar. There is maybe über-better solution than that, I'm a sys guy not a web specialist. In your case, better use FTP.

Comment: Yes I follow - local server is Ubuntu - just not sure where I can move files to so that remote can access.